# Border-radius changing in Chrome

Tags: html, css

When I use border-radius on DIV that is wrapping UL, after hovering the links inside UL, I'm losing the radius in Chrome.

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="middle">
    <ul class="bmenu">
        <li><a href="#home"/>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cv"/>CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects"/>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"/>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/TYgP6/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under bmenu class, you have to remove position:relative.

```
.bmenu{/*position:relative;*/}
```

I have updated the same [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TYgP6/3/). You can have a look.
Hope this helps.

Comment: hey @DimitarBosevski why you unchecked the tick here? :(

Answer (score 0):

```
.bmenu{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width:100%; 
height:60px;    
    color:#000;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;   
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

}
try this code replacing yours.you gave position relative to `.bmenu` which you need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the CSS property for Webkit - `-webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;` - that should solve it.

Comment: Does not change anything. Still same problem.